# JADE form submit not caught although route exists

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

I am using JADE, node.js, and express to create a table to select some data.
Everything is running on localhost.
When I try the route /climateParamSelect it works and displays what I would like to see including URL encoded elements.

Routing to this code snippet is in app.js but I confirmed that it works using /climateParamSelect?test=test. The routes are located in climateParamSelect.js

```
router.get('/', async function(req, res, next) {
    console.log('GET');
    console.log(req.query);
});

router.post('/', async function(req, res, next) {
    console.log('POST');
    console.log(req.params);
});
module.exports = router;
```

The code in app.js may be important after all, so here is an excerpt:

```
const express = require('express');
var tableSelectRouter = require('./routes/tableSelect');
var cpSelectRouter = require('./routes/climateParamSelect');
var app = express();
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use('/climateParamSelect', cpSelectRouter);
app.use('/tableSel', tableSelectRouter);
```

When I use the submit button of the following page it is invoked but for some reason, the route above is never taken. Instead, it displays: waiting for localhost.

```
html
  head
    title= title
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/style.css')
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css')
    script(src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.1/jquery.min.js')  
    script(src='https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js')  
    script.
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#selTable').DataTable();
        });
body
  form(name='productionSelect', method='post', action='/climateParamSelect')
    div#wrapper
      h1 Select production data for feature generation
      br
      table#selTable.display
        thead
          tr
            th headers
            //... 
        tbody
          tr
            td 
              input(type='checkbox',id='#{r}',name='#{r}')
            td 
            //...   
      br
      input(type='submit',value='Select Production',name='prodSubmit',data-transition='fade', data-theme='c')
```

What am I missing here?

Thank you

Comment: What address is shown in the browser after you post the form?

Comment: The address never changes. Just hangs waiting for localhost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The browser will sit there spinning until it receives a response, and there is no response sent in your route.  I'm sure you'll want to render a view, but to test it quickly just use `res.send` and a string.

The second issue is in how you're reading the data sent from the client.  `req.params` is used for dynamic URL parsing with variables in the route.  To handle form data (which is what you're sending here) you can use `req.body`.

Changing your route to this should fix your issues:

```
router.post('/climateParamSelect', async function(req, res, next) {
    console.log('POST');
    console.log(req.body);
    res.send("hello");
});
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll take that into account. The issue seems to be elsewhere, though. For clarification, I added a part of the app.js including the routes involved.

Comment: So the rendering failed without sending any output so the posting page kept waiting. Thank you.